# Lower attic floor joists to increase head room

Tags: ceiling, attic, joists

An old home I am interested in buying has 10' ceilings on the main level and an attic with 7' clearance.
[image]

I would like to replace the ceiling joists (*or attic floor joists*) in order to lower the main level ceiling to 8' and increase head clearance in the attic in order to make it a master suite.
The main level square footage is just under 900 sq ft.

The home was built in 1922 and has had zero renovations since then, all original inside (horrible kitchen). So I do not think pre-fab trusses were used.  It has a full basement.  Due to age and condition I know I am going into this as a full renovation project, but for $60K it seems worth it, particularly since neighboring homes go for 3x that.  I paid for a full inspection and the home is solid, just seriously dated.  I really need to use the attic space though.  I will try to find those episodes of This Old House that @FreeMan mentioned.

Comment: No idea of cost without more details.  But it might be cheaper to raise the roof.  That's a more standard approach IMO.

Comment: What is the type of roof? Those joists may be part of the roof construction.

Comment: A picture of the attic roof joists and attic floor joist would help. @SolarMike is correct. The floor joists and the roof joists could be acting together as your structural roof system. Also, what are the size of the floor joists and roof joists and spacing?

Comment: If it is a balloon structure it may be possible but if the first story was built then the 2nd added probably not feasible. Is there a basement?

Comment: Is it doable? Sure! But it may require essentially rebuilding the house, but it's certainly "doable". Potential cost: Material cost in your area plus: A) $0 in labor because you're doing it yourself (add in pizza costs if you're recruiting friends); or B) $$$$ thousands in labor because you're hiring an architect to properly redesign the structure, a demolition company to tear out the interior and a construction company to rebuild the interior. This is a snarky way of saying that this is _far_ too broad a question to be answered on [diy.se]. There are just too many variables.

Comment: Watch the first couple of episodes of a recent season of _This Old House_ (they're available online for free). That is, essentially, what you're getting yourself into. I'm not trying to _discourage you_ from doing this, I just want you to understand that this is _not_ a small endeavor to be undertaken lightly - you're looking at a _major_ renovation. In this case, you're really buying the dirt, location, views, etc., and _not_ the house itself.

Comment: Do you have any clue if the roof is old-school rafter-and-joist construction, or uses prefab trusses instead? That might be the key to how this is done....

Comment: I edited my original question to include more information.

Comment: The reason a picture of the attic is important, is because we can “see” things to help make a recommendation.

Comment: @LeeSam how does one add a photo to this site?  I haven't been able to figure it out!

Comment: @MelSandonana -- hit the [edit] link on your question in "share edit ..." at the bottom left, then use the button that looks like a sun-and-mountain to insert pictures

Comment: @MelSandonana [edit] your post. Just above the text entry box is a row of icons. Click the "sun & mountains" icon and it will open a box where you can drag an image file from your computer to be uploaded. [diy.se] will upload the image and host it for you. You can include multiple images, but must upload them one at a time.

Comment: If you'll take a couple of minutes to take the [tour] and read through the [help] (especially on asking question) you'll learn this trick and more!

Comment: Now can you add pics of the attic?

Comment: Ceiling joists / attic floor joists are frequently structural in non-truss construction. *i.e.* not being prefab trusses does not make the forces trying to flatten the roof and spread the walls go away. Some part of the construction has to resist them, and those are usually it.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt if you’ll be able to add an upstairs room without a special variance from your Building Department.

There are several issues: 1) Its a structural change so you’ll need a Building Permit, 2) the Code requires a minimum ceiling height, 3) minimum floor area required for habitable rooms, 4) window required in habitable rooms and if it’s a sleeping room, an egress window is required.

1. Not only is a Building Permit required, but if the value of the structure increases 25% or more, then the entire structure will need to be brought up to code. (Each State has a different threshold for this requirement, so check with your local Building Department.)

2. The minimum ceiling height for habitable rooms is 7’, but 50% of the floor area can have a sloping ceiling, but none can be lower than 5’. (See ICC R305)
3. The minimum habitable room size is 70 square feet and the minimum dimension in any direction cannot be less than 7’. (See ICC R304) Remember, those dimensions must meet the room height dimensions noted above.
4. You’ll need to add a window (or skylight if not a sleeping room.

Btw, a habitable room is defined as a room used for living, sleeping eating or cooking. Bathrooms, closets, halls, storage, or utility spaces are not considered habitable spaces.

Also, your new stairway must meet the current code too, including maximum riser height, minimum tread depth, etc.

Summary: Regardless of the structural adequacy of your floor and foundation system, there are many requirements that will be difficult meet. I’d recommend meeting with your local Building Officials to insure you are eligible.

Comment: All excellent points! Hiring a local architect to do the design work will likely bring in all the required local knowledge, including contacts with structural engineers to ensure any modifications (as opposed to replacements) of structural elements will be sufficient.